# Symfony/Doctrine: issue with $this->getRoute()->getObject, only some records being retrieved

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Post table:

```
id   name   content
 1   test1  generated from fixture
 2   test2  generated
 3   test3  generated
 4   post1  this is actual post
 5   post2  real
```

Routing:

```
post_show:
  url: /:name
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Posts, type: object, allow_empty: true}
  param: { module: post, action: show, name:test1}
```

Using `$this->getRoute()->getObject();` in the action *will return object fine* for example.com/test1, example.com/test2, example.com/test3, will return nothing for all other queries (e.g. example.com/post1). What could be causing this?

* I believe the only difference between the records that are returned(*test* records) and the ones that don't(*post*) is that the *test* records were generated from my fixture

Comment: please show all columns for those rows

Comment: Did you check if everything is actually in the table? Loading fixtures removes previous content.

Comment: Yea, everything is in the table. I might add that I can access them directly no problem. They simply don't get returned when I'm using getRoute()->getObject(); Could it be something with using :name in the routing?

Comment: You should set the method_for_query option and define a method to call there to get the object(s).

Comment: May be it's about the attribute "name" itself. You should use a slug to construct your URL. Some hidden spaces at the end of the string or special chars could cause this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my example:

routing.yml

```
book_list:
  url:      /api/books.:sf_format
  class:    sfDoctrineRoute
  options:  { model: Book, type: list, method: getActiveWithAuthor }
  param:    { module: book, action: list, sf_format: json }
  requirements:
    sf_format: (?:json|html)
```

actions.class.php

```
public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request) {
  $this->books = BookTable::getActiveWithAuthor($request->getGetParameters());
}
```

BookTable.class.php

```
public static function getActiveWithAuthor(array $parameters) {
  $bookQuery = BookQuery::create()
  ->addSelf()
  ->addAuthor();

  if(isset($parameters['date_from']))  
    $bookQuery->andWhere('b.updated_at > ?', $parameters['date_from']);
  return $bookQuery->execute();
}
```

This is just example, but it shows how it works.
Use type: list, method: yourQueryMethod and so on.